# Frequency Range from FFT using vDSP

Tags: accelerate-framework, vdsp

I have an array of values as input which can be plotted as follows…

[image]

Using `vDSP_zvmagsD` I get an array that I can plot as follows…

[image]

How do I get the frequency range that I need to label the x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of your frequency bins depend on the sampling rate of your input signal and the size of your FFT window:

input frequency / input samples = hz/frequency bin

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-relation-between-fft-length-and-frequency-resolution) you can find a more detailed answer by electronics stackexchange user Mark. There you will also find useful information about the tradeof between frequency resolution (bin size) and temporal resolution (when does which frequency occur)

Comment: Is one value in the second graph one frequency bin?

Comment: yes. i edited my answer to include a link to a more detailed answer!